# Placement of de-caps for power pin on PCB

Tags: power-supply, pcb, layout

I am debating placement of de-caps on bottom layer for Top side connector pin (Power).

Does it have to be in order, 1 or 2 ?

1. First series resistor / Then 1uF cap / Then 0.1uF cap/ Then via to connector pad
2. First series resistor / Then via to connector pad / Then 0.1uF cap / Then 1uF cap.

[image]

IF your answer is 1, can you please explain why ?

Comment: Before that can be answered, please define if the connector pad left to resistor is an input or output, and what is right to the capacitors.

Comment: Hi, Connector is on top. There is via which connects top to bottom. Caps are placed in bottom and via is connected. Resistor is there for isolation of power supply

Comment: Why is GND plane/fill (assumption) not covering one of the connections?

Comment: Because GND in this case is AGND. SO i have resistor which connects De-cap ground to Main ground